# Get reference to vue3 composition api shadowroot

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, web-component, vue-composition-api

how can I get a reference to the shadowroot of web components using vue3 composition api?

With Options api this would do:

```
<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    const shadowRoot = this.$el.parentNode
  }
}
```

I tried to get it with getCurrentInstance(), but to no avail :/

Would greatly appreciate any tips =)

## got it to work:

WC:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useWindi } from '../use/useWindi'
defineProps<{ title: string }>()
useWindi()
</script>
```

hook:

```
import { ref, onUpdated, onMounted, getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'

export const useWindi = () => {
  const shadowRoot = ref<ShadowRoot>()

  onUpdated(() => {
    if(!shadowRoot.value) return
    shadowRoot.value.adoptedStyleSheets = [(window as any).windiSheet];
  })

  onMounted(() => {
    shadowRoot.value = getCurrentInstance()?.vnode?.el?.parentNode
    if(!shadowRoot.value) return
    shadowRoot.value.adoptedStyleSheets = [(window as any).windiSheet];
  })
}
```

I basically wanted to adopt the windicss stylesheet in my components.

Comment: ``parentNode`` refers to a DOM Element. If it has a shadowRoot its: ``this.$el.parentNode.shadowRoot``

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it:

```
const shadowRoot = ref(null)

onMounted(() => {
  shadowRoot.value = getCurrentInstance().vnode.el.parentNode
})
```